# Undefined method `image' for #<Article::ActiveRecord_Relation.Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed gem 'paperclip' and used it as show in railscasts.Image appears in the page "show", but in the page "index" show me error:

```
undefined method `image' for #<Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbab4814310>
```

This is my index.html.erb

```
<% @article.each do |article| %>
      <div class="main-page-blocks">
      <%= image_tag @article.image.url(:small) %>
      <h3><%= article.title %></h3>
      <div class="main-page-articles"><%= article.body %></div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

this is my model article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "150x150"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

where is wrong?

Comment: Have you done the paperclip-specific migration? A la `rails generate paperclip article image`.

Comment: yes, here there are http://pastie.org/9614395

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is where the problem is:

```
<%= image_tag @article.image.url(:small) %>
```

You're calling `image` on `@article` when it should just be `article` which is the instance variable defined in the `each` block.

Update as follows:

```
<% @article.each do |article| %>
    <div class="main-page-blocks">
      <%= image_tag article.image.url(:small) %>
      <h3><%= article.title %></h3>
      <div class="main-page-articles"><%= article.body %></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you've defined `@article` in your pastie.  In this question your `@article` is a Active Record Relation not an instance of `Article`.  In your pastie, `@article` must be an instance of `Article`.